# How to concat corresponding elements of two arrays in pypspark dataframe with spark transformation?

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, concatenation

I have two ArrayType columns, and I wanna concatenate corresponding values for them in a new StringType column.
I'm wondering if it's possible using spark transformations and not UDFs.

```
input:
col1        col2
['1','2']   ['ABC', 'DEF']

output:
col3
'1:ABC_2:DEF'
```

Comment: look at spark 2.4 array functions, `arrays_zip` should work, although you need seql expressions for that, see e.g. https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/apache-spark-2.4-functions.html

Comment: arrays_zip gives an struct as output. I want a string as output.

Comment: Both arrays will have exact same elements?

Comment: yes it is guaranteed that both of them have the same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
a = [(['1','2'], ['ABC', 'DEF'])]
df = spark.createDataFrame(a, ['col1', 'col2'])
df.show()

+------+----------+
|  col1|      col2|
+------+----------+
|[1, 2]|[ABC, DEF]|
+------+----------+
```

Now we create a map from the two columns, and convert into json string:

```
df = df.withColumn('col3', F.map_from_arrays('col1', 'col2'))
df = df.withColumn('col3', F.to_json('col3'))

# you can now just operate on the string:
df = df.withColumn('col3', F.regexp_replace('col3', '"', ''))
df = df.withColumn('col3', F.regexp_replace('col3', ',', '_'))
df = df.withColumn('col3', F.regexp_replace('col3', '\{', ''))
df = df.withColumn('col3', F.regexp_replace('col3', '\}', ''))
df.show(truncate=False)

+------+----------+-----------+
|col1  |col2      |col3       |
+------+----------+-----------+
|[1, 2]|[ABC, DEF]|1:ABC_2:DEF|
+------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.